# Passing values between views using UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to pass an integer between two views. When I return from View1 to MainView, the value is not passed and the NSLog(@"Changed map") is not showing in the console. I looked for the answer and tried everything, but it just won't work! Feels like somethings wrong with the delegate...

Any ideas?

View1.h

```
@class FlipsideViewController;

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
    - (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
    -(void)flipsideViewControllerSelectionChangedToIndex:(int)index;
    @end

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mapType;

- (IBAction)valueChangedMap:(id)sender;

@end
```

View1.m

```
-(IBAction)valueChangedMap:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerSelectionChangedToIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]];
    NSLog (@"%d",[sender selectedSegmentIndex]);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

MainView.h

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> {}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property(weak) id<FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

MainView.m

```
-(void)flipsideViewControllerSelectionChangedToIndex:(int)index {
    NSLog(@"Changed map");

    if (index == 0) mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    if (index == 1) mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
    if (index == 2) mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the delegate is not nil? Where do you set the delegate? Also, your 'Changed map' method should probably use a switch with a default case or an if/else to make sure that values you don't expect get caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need an actual delegate property on your view1, and your mainView simply needs to respond to that delegate protocol. Here is what your delegate protocol should look like:

```
@property(nonatomic,unsafe_unretained) id delegate;
```

Now in your code when, mainview presents or pushes view1 you need to wire up the delegate like this (pseudo code):

```
view1.delegate = self;
```

Also a few nitpicks... you should never have a viewcontroller dismissing itself, mainView should dismiss the view1 when that 'finished' delegate method fires. In addition you should always check that a delegate responds to a selector before firing:

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(yourselectorname)]) {
    [self.delegate yourselectorname];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem was that I didnt wire up the delegate in mainview.